# If $x $ is a normal distribution and $ y $ is a binomial distribution, what is the density function of $x+y$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $x $ is a normal distribution and $ y $ is a binomial distribution, find the density function of $x+y$.

It is the first time for me to deal with the sum of discrete and continuous random variables. I assume it is different from the sum of both continuous r.v. I am not familiar with the steps. Thanks!

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming independence:  Assume $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ and $Y \sim B(n,p)$ and let $Z=X+Y$.  Then $F_z(z)=P(Z\le z)=P(X+Y\le z)$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n P(Y=k)P(X\le z-k)$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{(n-k)}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{z-k}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$.
Density $f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n$$ \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{(n-k)}$$e^{-\frac{(z-k-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$.

Comment: I think $P(X+Y\le z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n P(X\le z-k)$ should be replaced with $P(X+Y\le z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n P(X\le z-k) P(Y=k)$

Comment: You are right.  I forgot to type it in.  The next equation is correct.  I edited the answer.